# MVC Post action not binding correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I have 3 properties in my `Scenario` model of type `ScenarioMeasures`. They seem to be POSTing correctly, but the `ScenarioTargets` numbers are being used for all 3 properties. I have to believe they're not binding properly for some reason. Why might that be?

### Models

```
public class EditScenarioViewModel
{
    public Scenario scenario { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> locations { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> fiscalPeriods { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> effectivePeriods { get; set; }
}

public class Scenario
{
    //lots of other stuff, then...

    [Required]
    public ScenarioMeasures Adjustments { get; set; }

    public ScenarioMeasures BaselineData { get; set; }

    public ScenarioMeasures ScenarioTargets { get; set; }

    //more stuff...
}

public class ScenarioMeasures
{
    public decimal RGURate { get; set; }
    public decimal RevRate { get; set; }
    public int RevAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal VideoRate { get; set; }
    public decimal TSR { get; set; }
    public decimal Home { get; set; }
    public decimal CustomerRetentionRate { get; set; }
}
```

### Controller

```
// POST: Scenario/Edit/5
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, EditScenarioViewModel viewModel)
...
```

#### Posted Data

```
scenario.BaselineData.RGURate:0.77
scenario.Adjustments.RGURate:0.01
scenario.ScenarioTargets.RGURate:0.78

scenario.BaselineData.RevRate:0.83
scenario.Adjustments.RevRate:0.02
scenario.ScenarioTargets.RevRate:0.85

scenario.BaselineData.RevAmount:37931
scenario.Adjustments.RevAmount:300
scenario.ScenarioTargets.RevAmount:38231

scenario.BaselineData.VideoRate:0.73
scenario.Adjustments.VideoRate:0.04
scenario.ScenarioTargets.VideoRate:0.77

scenario.BaselineData.TSR:0.02
scenario.Adjustments.TSR:0.05
scenario.ScenarioTargets.TSR:0.07

scenario.BaselineData.Home:0.00
scenario.Adjustments.Home:0.00
scenario.ScenarioTargets.Home:0.00

scenario.BaselineData.CustomerRetentionRate:0.00
scenario.Adjustments.CustomerRetentionRate:0.00
scenario.ScenarioTargets.CustomerRetentionRate:0.00
```

#### Bound Data

```
Adjustments     {BusinessModels.Models.ScenarioMeasures}      BusinessModels.Models.ScenarioMeasures
CustomerRetentionRate   0       decimal
Home                    0       decimal
RevAmount               38231   int
RevRate                 0.85    decimal
RGURate                 0.78    decimal
TSR                     0.07    decimal
VideoRate               0.77    decimal

BaselineData    {BusinessModels.Models.ScenarioMeasures}      BusinessModels.Models.ScenarioMeasures
CustomerRetentionRate   0       decimal
Home                    0       decimal
RevAmount               38231   int
RevRate                 0.85    decimal
RGURate                 0.78    decimal
TSR                     0.07    decimal
VideoRate               0.77    decimal

ScenarioTargets {BusinessModels.Models.ScenarioMeasures}      BusinessModels.Models.ScenarioMeasures
CustomerRetentionRate   0       decimal
Home                    0       decimal
RevAmount               38231   int
RevRate                 0.85    decimal
RGURate                 0.78    decimal
TSR                     0.07    decimal
VideoRate               0.77    decimal
```

Comment: So, you are watching the POST request and seeing the data that is being sent, then you set a breakpoint on your action method in Visual Studio and that is how you are seeing the discrepancy between what was posted and what the controller action received into it's model binding?

Comment: precisely. the "posted data" is from chrome, and the "bound data" is what's inside the `scenario` object in the VM inside the controller action.

Comment: problem is definitely with viewmodel code and may be also with cshtml but everything depends . please show us how you built the data in-order to send it to controller in viewmodel

Comment: I'm using the TextBoxFor helper. For example: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.scenario.BaselineData.RGURate, "{0:n2}", new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", data_bind = "value: RGURateHistoric" })`

Comment: ok you using razor alrighty . i never done razor mix with knockout view models . can you post sample view part of your `adjustments` and `baselinedata` . just post a outer loop code with a single control inside . ex: `@using (@Html.beginform(//blah ... ` .

Comment: the VM I posted is on the server (MVC) side, but I am also using knockout. The values are sending from the browser correctly, as you can see in the data from the POST header from chrome. The rest of the object binds correctly, it's only these particular properties that are not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone runs into this in the future... it appears to be something related to nesting the same type of object (in this case, three `BusinessModels.Models.ScenarioMeasures`) more than one level down in the viewmodel.

Was able to resolve by doing individual fields in the viewmodel, then copying these "transfer" fields into the object in the controller. It's ugly, but it works.